# Who first used the notation $\mathcal{O}_K$ for ring of integers?

Tags: notation, algebraic-number-theory, math-history, integer-rings

I think this is a standard notation since almost every author uses it, but who came up with the notation? After all, what does $\mathcal{O}$ in $\mathcal{O}_K$ stand for? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I do not know but I would bet that Artin. Concerning the use of $\mathcal{O}$ it was surely for distinguish clearly that is a new kind of integers.

Comment: What it stands for is ["order."](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_%28ring_theory%29)

Comment: Could have been Dedekind

Comment: My God!. I wanted to say Dedekind. Believe me, please. Anyway it is not sure for the moment.

Comment: This is answered here: https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/2922/who-first-introduced-the-notation-mathcalo-in-algebraic-geometry-or-algebra/2924?noredirect=1